# cloud 9 — php file gets downloaded instead of executing

Tags: php, cloud9-ide

I am developing a project on Cloud9 platform and recently have run into the following issue. 
There is html page and php file that writes in .txt file data put in form on the html page:

```
process.php
<?php
$name = $_GET['email'];
$file = 'myText.txt';
file_put_contents($file, $name);
?>

index.html
form action="process.php" method="get">
<div class="label">email</div>
<div class="labeled">
<input type="text" name="email" class="text" >
</div>
<input type="submit" class="submit">
</form>
```

I run process.php using cloud9 web interface and then when submit button is clicked process.php gets dowloaded instead of executing. 
I know it has something to do with php settings but I'm not sure which exactly.

Comment: This is a web server mime type issue most likely, not a coding problem.

Comment: Are you visiting the php page using your application url, or using the preview feature of Cloud9? You should always run the apache server and access your php application via the application url (`http://<workspacename>-<username>.c9.io`). Do let me know if that doesn't help.

Comment: @Mutahhir I visit using c9 the preview feature (the project is based on c9 php workspace template) Here is the link to php script that I want to execute on server: https://preview.c9.io/pmtime/fut2/process.php

Comment: The preview feature is to just view the file. If you'd like to run your php script, please start the apache server and try accessing it from the url mentioned in my earlier comment.

Comment: Also check out: https://docs.c9.io/docs/writing-a-php-app

Comment: I did start the server but I used preview link. Now it works. Thanks!